# Implementation of a function that finds the minimum of two values

Tags: python, function

```
def minimum (pNum1,pNum2):
#subprogram here

return ()

inNum = int (input ("Please enter a number.  0 to quit."))
minNum = inNum
maxNum = inNum

while (inNum !=0):

# ===> minNum =  # here is where I will call the subprogram.
# ===> maxNum =
# ===> theSum =
inNum = int (input ("Please enter a number.  0 to quit."))
```

I have attempted to write a function to find the minimum of numbers entered. The user keeps entering numbers until they press 0.

I would like to attempt finding out how to get the maximum and how to add. I do not want to use the built in min/max that Python uses. I have looked on the net and this forum.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That functionality exists as `min()` already.

Comment: @KlausD. "I do not want to use the built in min/max that Python uses."

Comment: The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#using-python-as-a-calculator) shows how to add numbers. You can write your own `min` and `max` function using the [mathematical definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima#Definition)

Comment: It seems you forgot to put your attempt in your code.

Comment: What happens if the smallest number *is* zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an implementation of a function that finds the minimum of two values:

```
def minimum(pNum1, pNum2):
    if pNum1 < pNum2:
        return pNum1
    else:
        return pNum2
```

A program to find the minimum, maximum, and the sum:

```
inNum = int(input("Please enter a number.  0 to quit."))
minNum = inNum
maxNum = inNum
theSum = inNum
while inNum != 0:
    inNum = int(input("Please enter a number.  0 to quit."))
    if inNum == 0:
        break
    minNum = minimum(minNum, inNum)
    maxNum = maximum(maxNum, inNum)
    theSum += inNum
print minNum, maxNum, theSum
```

I will leave it to you to write the `maximum` function.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you very much David!! Great help!!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you want to do that. 
You could test which of the variable is the lower :

```
def minimum (pNum1,pNum2):
    if pNum1 < pNum2:
       return pNum1
    else:
       return pNum2
```

Comment: Thank you Manu. I have to do it for a mini assignment. I did try that but the problem is users can keep adding numbers until they press 0. Then the smallest number is taken from that list. I am looking into lists. I know you have to declare a list by using listName = [] then you have to append to add to that but I am stuck.